# Best tools / processes to convert an existing HTML5 website to a mobile version

Tags: html, mobile

I'm looking to create a mobile version of our website. What's a good way to provide the best, most fully featured version.

We have HTML5 and CSS3 Website. Is any Converting is possible?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think you mean CSS3, right?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to consider when converting your site, what size screens and devices are you going to support - just phones or pads too?  Also what is the content / functionality of your site.  If it's fairly static display sort of data then you may consider "Responsive Design" (lots of links if you google it).  You modify your layout to handle the screen sizes.  You could use Modernizr or something like that to determine what functionality the device has and determine how to skin / handle navigation, form data, etc.  I don't think you'll find anything to just "port" your site (other than paying somebody else to do it)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you plan on having similar content on your mobile version of your website that you do on desktop version, if so you could use media queries to configure the styling of your site to best fit various mobile screen sizes, such as:

```
/* Media Queries
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

@media handheld and (max-width:480px),
       screen and (max-device-width: 480px),
       screen and (mx-width: 600px) {
  /* then modify css for the small screen such as centering headers, setting inherit widths etc */
}
```